# Dataset capacities

Tags: ado.net

Is there any limit of rows for a dataset. Basically I need to generate excel files with data extracted from SQL server and add formatting. There are 2 approaches I have. Either take enntire data (around 4,50,000 rows) and loops through those in .net code OR loop through around 160 records, pass every record as an input to proc, get the relavant data, generate the file and move to next of 160. Which is the best way? Is there any other way this can be handled?
If I take 450000 records at a time, will my application crash?

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: My rule of thumb is an ASP.NET application will recycle at 4000-5000 dataset rows. For winforms, I would make a wild guess of that amount times the number of GB of memory you have (5K rows per GB of memory). The dataset is massively space inefficient and worse, needs to be entirely in memory. Your entire computer will behave as if it is under extremely low memory conditions if you manage to load 1/2 million rows into a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I need to generate excel files with data extracted from SQL server and add formatting

A DataSet is generally not ideal for this. A process that loads a dataset, loops over it,  and then discards it, means that the memory from the first row processed won't be released until the last row is processed.

You should use a [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead. This discards each row once its processed through  a subsequent call to Read.

> Is there any limit of rows for a dataset

At the very least since the DataRowCollection.Count Property is an int its limited to 4,294,967,295 rows, however there may be some other constraint that makes it smaller.

From your comments this is outline of how I might construct the loop

```
using (connection)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
               @"SELECT Company,Dept, Emp Name 
                 FROM Table 
                 ORDER BY Company,Dept, Emp Name );
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    string CurrentCompany = "";
    string CurrentDept = "";
    string LastCompany = "";
    string LastDept = "";
    string EmpName = "";
    SomeExcelObject xl = null;

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            CurrentCompany  = reader["Company"].ToString();
            CurrentDept = reader["Dept"].ToString();

            if (CurrentCompany != LastCompany || CurrentDept != LastDept)
            {  
                 xl = CreateNewExcelDocument(CurrentCompany,CurrentDept);
            }
            LastCompany = CurrentCompany;
            LastDept = CurrentDept;

           AddNewEmpName (xl, reader["EmpName"].ToString() );

        }
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: r u suggesting to go with option 1 or 2?

Comment: You should use a DataReader. This will allow you to process each record as its retrieved. That way you don't need to concern yourself with limiting the rows retrieved from the database. That didn't seem to be in either option you mentioned

Comment: I can not use data reader as it will return only 1 row at a time. My data is like below <br/>Company Dept Emp Name
ABC Accounts          Name 1
ABC Technology Name 2
ABC Marketing  Name 3
DEF Accounts          Name 4
DEF Technology Name 5
DEF Marketing          Name 6
GHI Accounts          Name 7
GHI Technology Name 8
GHI Marketing  Name 9
 here each company and dept combination will have 1 esxel file

Comment: there are several way to deal with that. 1) Get the distinct company/department names in the query. 2) Order by company/department and check on each loop if the dept or company has changed. 3) Keep a collection of company/departments in memory and check that on each iteration.

Comment: wht I got is, take company-department in a collection. Pass each combination to the database and get associated employee names generate the excel file and move to next company-dept combination. As per my data output, it wll hit to database around 2000-3000 times as there are approx 2500 unique combinations of company-dept

Comment: That's one approach. I gave three. Only the first requires multiple round trips to the db, but then again if you're making 2500 excel files I suspect it will take some time. By the way did you consider doing this in [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)

Comment: yes. formatting excels is not possible in SSIS. Again i believe i wll hv to run another script for formating. And its going to take time for sure. I just wanted to know the best way of doing this.

Comment: I added some pseudo code that may better describe what I'm trying to get across

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to read 4 million rows into your application at one time. You should instead use a DataReader or other cursor-like method and look at the data a row at a time. Otherwise, even if your application does run, it'll be extremely slow and use up all of the computer's resources